# Keep child process open while it polls data?

Tags: c#, process

Hey so I am working on something that does the following logic.

Create Parent App, Create Child Process, Have Child process poll data, Send data to Parent App,

Everything is setup fine and is working when I manually Console.WriteLine in child process and I receive that fine in the Parent App.
The problem lies in the fact that the child process is polling input from an xbox controller and then sending that information to the parent app. The problem is that the only way I can think of keeping the child process alive is put in a while loop in Main, once a certain condition is met than close.
However the while loop isn't allowing the process to poll since its just stuck in the loop. 
The main caveat is that the polling is done through events so I can't manually poll.

Any ideas on how to keep the passive event type polling to work while keeping the process open?

Here is the setup:

```
static Battler m_battler = new Battler();
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        m_battler = new Battler();

       string[] procArgs = (string[])args;
       if (procArgs.Length == 0)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("No Args passed");
           Console.Read();
           return;
       }

       parsedArg = procArgs[0].Split('^');

       m_battler.NumBattles = Convert.ToInt32(parsedArg[0]);
```

m_battler has the controller in it and then that uses events to call a function to parse the input and sends it to the parent app, again there is no poll loop its just something like m_xboxController.ProcessedDebugOutput += new XboxController.DebugOutputHandler(Result);

Result parses everything then sends it to the parent app

```
  private void AddHandler()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("handler");
            m_xboxController = new XboxController();
            TestDelegate testDel = new TestDelegate(Result);
            m_xboxController.ProcessedDebugOutput += new XboxController.DebugOutputHandler(testDel);

            threadInit = false;
        }

        public void Init(int consoleNum, string activeConsole)
        {
            ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(AddHandler);

            outputThread = new Thread(ts);

            outputThread.Start();

            while (threadInit)
            {
                continue;
            }
         }
```

Here is more detail on what is happening

Comment: why not run the poll loop in a separate thread?

Comment: I have tried that, but its all event driven, i don't know how to exactly to get that to work when working with a thread. I will add a bit more info into the question

Answer (score 0):

Events are not magical. Depending on how the `Battler` class or the inner mechanism works, the event handler will be called:

1. Synchronously
2. Asynchronously on a separate thread
3. Asynchronously by invoking on the main thread

The 1st and 2nd option will work with an infinite loop (option 2 will require some thread synchronisation). It appears you believe option 3 is the case.

Before I suggest a solution, could you provide more info on exactly how the event is fired?  What makes you think it's dispatched as a message to the main thread and needs to be read from message loop? What is this XboxController class you're using?

Comment: Hey sorry i was away for the weekend, The event system is step up in a way where the controller will call a Result function through an event handler. I don't have access to the Controller event system so i can't modify that at all. So i register the callback function and the controller will call it. So what i am thinking is that the event system will fire off but the Result method won't get called since of the loop in main. I can't force call anything in the Controller either to manually poll for data.

Comment: m_xboxController.ProcessedDebugOutput += new XboxController.DebugOutputHandler(Result);

This is how i set up the event, so as i said before i can't manually call the event handler. :(

Comment: That's not the point at all. What is this XboxController class? Google doesn't show much. Post a link to some sort of documentation/project page so I can have a look.